# How to add any classes to the standard java libraries?

Tags: java, open-source

As Java is an open source: if we have developed good classes which may help anybody.. Can we add them to standard Java library? If yes: how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most useful classes are maintained and distributed via libraries and not included in the JDK/JRE. The apache commons libraries are a very good example: extremely useful but not part of Java.

If your question is of theoretical nature - JSR's are the way to add something to Java. If your question is practical (iaw, you have something you'd like to contribute), I'd practically say: forget about it, put everything in a library and host it on sourceforge (or something else).

Answer (score 5):

File a [JSR](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/overview).

Comment: If there's only small changes, that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Just for interest's sake: [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) is considered by many to be a very useful `LayoutManager`, and its creators and a lot of its users are lobbying to get it adopted into the standard library. They hope to get it into Java 7. We'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few [mailing lists](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo) associated with ongoing Java/JDK development.  These would be the best places to start for suggesting new classes and utilities to add to the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Submit patches to the OpenJDK project, via the [mailing lists](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo) mentioned by jsight and then to make it official go the [JSR](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/overview) route mentioned by Ignacio, ideally with some community support.